# Adding text to a dynamically created DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, momentjs

I'm trying to create `<div>` elements with child `<p>` elements; the `<div>` elements are being assigned a class of "clock" + a number (increments). While the elements themselves seem to be created, adding text (in my case a moment object) to the `<p>` element doesn't work.

HTML:

```
<body>
      <select class="tz_list" name="timezones">
          <option value="default">Please Select a Timezone</option>
      </select>
      <input type="button" name="addClock" value="Add Clock" class="button">
</body>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var now = moment();
    console.log(now);
    //var repeat = setInterval(displayTime, 200);
    var tzones = moment.tz.names();
    tzones.forEach(function(key,value){
        $('<option/>').val(key).html(key).appendTo('.tz_list');
    });
    var repeat;
    var clock_count = 1;
    var timezone ="";


    function displayTime(timezone, clock_number) {
       console.log(timezone);
       var location = moment().tz(timezone).format("ddd, MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm:ss");
       console.log(location);
       //$('.clock '+clock_number)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = timezone;
       var selector = '.clock '+clock_number.toString() + ' p';
       console.log(selector);
       //$('.clock '+clock_number.toString()).css({"height":"100px", "width":"500px"});
       $(selector).text(location.toString());
     };

    $('.button').on('click', function(e){
       console.log(e.target.value);
       var div = '<div class="clock '+clock_count.toString()+'"><p></p></div>';
       $(div).insertAfter('.button');
       clock_count+=1;
       displayTime(timezone, clock_count-1);

    });

    $('.tz_list').on('change', function(event){
        console.log(event.target.value);
        timezone = event.target.value;

    });

});
```

What am I missing?
Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lycan1385/xpa5ux9e/2/)

Comment: I can see that it is working, just your <p> has no text so it seams not working, but if you check the source code you will find the Div elements are adding correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead creating class "clock " try to create with out giving space. It will work.

```
    function displayTime(timezone, clock_number) {
   console.log(timezone);
   var location = moment().tz(timezone).format("ddd, MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm:ss");
   console.log(location);
   //$('.clock '+clock_number)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = timezone;
   var selector = '.clock'+clock_number.toString() + ' p';
   console.log(selector);
   //$('.clock'+clock_number.toString()).css({"height":"100px", "width":"500px"});
   $('.clock'+clock_number.toString()).text(timezone);
   $(selector).text(location.toString());
 };
$('.button').on('click', function(e){
   console.log(e.target.value);
   var div = '<div class="clock'+clock_count.toString()+'"><p></p></div>';
   $(div).insertAfter('.button');
   clock_count+=1;
   displayTime(timezone, clock_count-1);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
$('.clock.'+clock_number.toString()).text(timezone);
```

add the "." after clock but is not a god practice add number as class, instead use something like clock_1 (or clock1 like the answer below)